3D figures looking worse in 14.1
I recently updated my Mathematica to 14.1 and my 3D figures started to look noticably worse.
Consider the two folllowing pictures


The first picture is a screenshot of how the figure looks like when I click on it and hold my mouse to rotate it.
The second picture is what the figure looks like when I release my hold. You can see some darker places at the edges of the picture (suggested by the top read arrows) as well as that the surfaces inside are not properly drawn up to the thick black line-segment (pointed to by the bottom red arrow).
In the end I care about what I can export, but exporting it as pdf or png the results look like picture on the right, while in previous versions of Mathematica the exports looked like in the left picture.
Downgrading back to 14.0 is out the question as that version on my PC was crashing when rendering my 3D plots and I am not sure I can downgrade to earlier versions, so I am rather looking for some other suggestions.
I ran Manjaro, Arch-based Linux distro, should it be relevant.
P.S.: Since I want to include the figures in a scientific article where the figures are pivotal, their exact appearence matters to me.

Maybe play with 3DRenderingEngine or 3DRenderingMethod. Or report it to WRI.

Try this way of exporting Export["file.pdf", graph, "AllowRasterization" -> True,   ImageResolution -> 600]
